# MS CRM update entity without change modified at and modified by

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've created a custom field in MS CRM 4 entiry used for calculations. Usually it would be filled by the plug-in handler.

How could I initialize this field for all records without changing the `"modified at"` and `"modified by"` fields?
Is it possible from Web Service API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard of people running a SQL UPDATE statements on the CRM tables without adverse effects.  I've even had MSFT premier support give me an UPDATE statement to fix a problem with a user's record.

Comment: I've seen this too. Obviously only applicable to on-premise, but I don't see any issue with this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to database for that task. I've found the workaround as the delayed change in plugin handler.

Thanks anyway.